# $.POST on a squarespace page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, squarespace

I have a custom form that posts to a 3rd party server as an appointment booking module. If i submit the form thru the action of the `<form>` tag i do recieve the email, but i would like to submit the form using $.POST so that i can alter the redirect URL.

I have jQuery running successfully on my site, and if i use:

```
$.post('URL', {data}).then(function () {alert('Form Submitted!')});
```

The redirect (or alert for this example) works fine, but the POST doesnt seem to actually run. Has anyone had a similar issue and found a way to resolve this?

ACTUAL CODE

I am using mailthis.to's API to avoid having to run a server just to do this

```
$('#sendForm').click(()=>{
$.post('https://mailthis.to/support@gadget-pro.com', {
  Name:$('#Name').val(),
  Email:$('#Email').val(),
  Phone:$('#Phone').val(),
  Device:$('#device').val(),
  Repair:$('#repairType').val(),
  Price:$('#price').val()
}).then(function (data) {
  location.href = 'https://gadget-pro.com/formconfirm'
});
```

`})`

Comment: are submitting all the necessary fields for the api, there might be a hidden input or something, post the code from the working form and the actual `$.post` you have that is not working

Comment: Try **console.log()** instead of alert/redirect to check the response. It seems that you are getting the successful response from the API.

Comment: Ive realized after more research that i can use a hidden input with a value of _after from the api to do this without using an AJAX POST

Answer (score 0):

I would say to update your code to return back the page. you are likely not triggering the post to page properly or there is an error.
alos console.log the post data before to know what is being sent.

update your code to

```
console.log(data);
$.post('URL', {data}).then(function (retpage) {console.log(retpage)});
```

Comment: the API's confirmation page html is returned successfully however the form submission is never recieved in email. Updating question now to reflect actual code